# Matlab crashes with Python 2.7 virtual environment on Linux [Manjaro]

Tags: linux, python, matlab, anaconda

So I have some code in Matlab that calls functions from Python's scikit-learn module. The problem is when I try to use Python 2.7 in a virtual environment created via Anaconda, it exits out with segmentation fault. This does not happen with Python 3.7 virtual environment created with Anaconda. The stack trace is as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Thu Jan 24 15:59:14 2019
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  Deployed            : false
  GNU C Library       : 2.28 stable
  Host Name           : h110
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID: 6257193
  MATLAB Root         : /run/media/mahieyin/STUFF/ProgramFiles/MATLAB/R2017a
  MATLAB Version      : 9.2.0.538062 (R2017a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.19.14-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 9 17:17:37 UTC 2019 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (12003000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f21e0bb2fa0
  RCX = 0000000000000100  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 00007f227bb2a698  RBP = 0000000001003f00
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 0000000000000000

   R8 = 0000000000000100   R9 = 00000000010267b0
  R10 = 000000000000000e  R11 = 000000000000000f
  R12 = 0000000000000002  R13 = 00000000010256c8
  R14 = 00007f21e0d51bd0  R15 = 00007f2293355850

  RIP = 00007f229c166c1e  EFL = 0000000000010283

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f229c166c1e                                 /usr/lib/libc.so.6+01420318
[  1] 0x00007f22933f642d /run/media/mahieyin/STUFF/ProgramFiles/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0+01106989 lh_insert+00000173
[  2] 0x00007f2293355c95 /run/media/mahieyin/STUFF/ProgramFiles/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0+00449685 OBJ_NAME_add+00000101
[  3] 0x00007f21b23638cd /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so+00923853 openssl_add_all_ciphers_int+00000829
[  4] 0x00007f21b231284a /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so+00591946
[  5] 0x00007f229c1df4ff                           /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0+00062719
[  6] 0x00007f21b232677a /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so+00673658 CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once+00000010
[  7] 0x00007f21b2312eac /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so+00593580 OPENSSL_init_crypto+00000572
[  8] 0x00007f21b230bde2 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so+00564706 init_hashlib+00000034
[  9] 0x00007f21b379418e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01024398 _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule+00000158
[ 10] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 11] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 12] 0x00007f21b3792e8c /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019532 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000188
[ 13] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 14] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 15] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 16] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 17] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 18] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 19] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 20] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[ 21] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 22] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 23] 0x00007f21b3792e8c /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019532 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000188
[ 24] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 25] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 26] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 27] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 28] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 29] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 30] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 31] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[ 32] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 33] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 34] 0x00007f21b3792e8c /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019532 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000188
[ 35] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 36] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 37] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 38] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 39] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 40] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 41] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 42] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[ 43] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 44] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 45] 0x00007f21b3792e8c /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019532 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000188
[ 46] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 47] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 48] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 49] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 50] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 51] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 52] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 53] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[ 54] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 55] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 56] 0x00007f21b3792ecc /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019596 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000252
[ 57] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 58] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 59] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 60] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 61] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 62] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 63] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 64] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[ 65] 0x00007f21b3792b1f /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01018655
[ 66] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 67] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 68] 0x00007f21b3792ecc /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019596 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000252
[ 69] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 70] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 71] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 72] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 73] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 74] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 75] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 76] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[ 77] 0x00007f21b3792b1f /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01018655
[ 78] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 79] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 80] 0x00007f21b3792ecc /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019596 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000252
[ 81] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 82] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 83] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 84] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 85] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 86] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 87] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 88] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[ 89] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[ 90] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[ 91] 0x00007f21b3792e8c /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019532 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000188
[ 92] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[ 93] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[ 94] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[ 95] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[ 96] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[ 97] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[ 98] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[ 99] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[100] 0x00007f21b3792b1f /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01018655
[101] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[102] 0x00007f21b3792578 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017208
[103] 0x00007f21b3792ecc /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019596 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000252
[104] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[105] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[106] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[107] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[108] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[109] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[110] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[111] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[112] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[113] 0x00007f21b3792899 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01018009
[114] 0x00007f21b3792f5d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019741 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000397
[115] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126
[116] 0x00007f21b36e5973 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00309619 PyObject_Call+00000067
[117] 0x00007f21b3777c38 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00908344 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+00000072
[118] 0x00007f21b377d638 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00931384 PyEval_EvalFrameEx+00021672
[119] 0x00007f21b37816c9 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00947913 PyEval_EvalCodeEx+00002025
[120] 0x00007f21b37818ea /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00948458 PyEval_EvalCode+00000026
[121] 0x00007f21b379141e /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01012766 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+00000174
[122] 0x00007f21b379169d /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01013405
[123] 0x00007f21b3792b1f /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01018655
[124] 0x00007f21b3792323 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01016611
[125] 0x00007f21b379262a /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01017386
[126] 0x00007f21b3792e8c /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+01019532 PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+00000188
[127] 0x00007f21b3776006 /home/mahieyin/.conda/envs/py27/lib/libpython2.7.so+00901126


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

I can't seem to find any similar problems on the web, apologies if this is a known issue or the wrong forum post. Also, the reason for asking this when it works with Python 3.7 is to figure out the root cause and fix it so that I can use whichever Python version at ease. Ty in advance.